# Run simple script on web page

Tags: python

I have made a simple game script that runs in the console. This game is in python 3.8. It's all been coded on repl.it and I want to run it on a url. I had a go with python anywhere but still struggled.

This is my code:

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

print("The vault has been locked for the night...")
combination = randint(1,1000)

safe_locked = True
int_invalid = True
duplicate = True
guesses_list = list()
one_o_one = 1001
lower_bound = 0
upper_bound = 1001
guess_count = 0
valid_guesses = 0

while safe_locked == True:

  while int_invalid == True:
    try:
      if guess_count > 0:
        if upper_bound == 1001:
          upper_bound -= 1
        if lower_bound == 0:
          lower_bound += 1
        guess = int(input("Take your guess at the combination between [" + str(lower_bound) + "-" + str(upper_bound) + "]..."))
      else:
        guess = int(input("Take your guess at the combination between [1-1000]..."))
        guess_count += 1
      if guess in guesses_list :
        guess += one_o_one
        duplicate = False
      if guess in range(lower_bound,upper_bound):
        guesses_list.append(guess)
        break
      else:
        if duplicate == False:
          print("Invalid combination! Make sure combination isn't a duplicate...")
        else:
          if upper_bound == 1001:
            upper_bound -= 1
          print("Invalid combination! Make sure combination is within [" + str(lower_bound) + "-" + str(upper_bound) + "]...")
          int_invalid = True
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid combination! Make sure combination only includes numbers...")

  valid_guesses += 1

  if guess_count == 1:
    if guess > combination:
      upper_bound = guess
    else:
      lower_bound = guess

  if guess == combination:
    print("The vault has opened... The jewels are yours!")
    safe_locked = False
    print("Total number of validated guesses required to gain access: " + str(valid_guesses))
    break
  else:
    if guess > combination:
      print("The combination is lower...")
    else:
      print("The combination is higher...")

  guesses_list.sort()
  y = np.array(guesses_list)
  x = combination
  lower,higher=y[y<x],y[y>x]

  if lower.size > 0 and higher.size > 0:
    lower_bound = lower[-1]
    upper_bound = higher[0]
    print("The combination is between [" + str(lower_bound) + "-" + str(upper_bound) + "]")

  if safe_locked == False:
    break
```

How would I have this work on eg python anywhere using flask (maybe??)..

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about why your code doesn't work in Python anywhere

Comment: You don't run Python scripts in web pages. You run web servers with Python that accept HTTP requests... If you want to run scripts in web pages, that would need to be done in Javascript, unless python supports webassembly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. SO is meant for specific problems, not tutorials or broad advice. If you're having a specific problem, please [edit] the question to clarify what it is. Otherwise try some tutorials like [Setting up Flask applications on PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/).

Comment: I am not sure if this is related, but you probably need to add your code as functions within a Flask app. The above does not look that way. Have you try flask at all?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Trinket.io](https://trinket.io/) to run it and then embed it into your own site using an iframe.